# Multi-group chat server in python twisted

Tags: python, chat, twisted

I am running a Chat Server using twisted framework, it works great for the one group but I need multiple groups so that user can join the particular group and he can send/recieve the messages to that particular group, so how to create more than one group or working functon 'joinroom(self,roomname)' and user will be redirected to that group ?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor,protocol                                           
from twisted.protocols import basic                                            
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory                  
import time                                                                              

def t():

return "["+ time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") +"] "                                          

class EchoProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):                                                  
  name = "Unnamed"                                                                     

  def connectionMade(self):                                                            

    self.transport.write("WhiteNOISE"+"\n")                                          
    self.sendLine("Enter A name Below...")                                           
    self.sendLine("")                                                                
    self.count = 0                                                                   
    self.factory.clients.append(self)                                                
    self.factory.group.append(self)                                                  
    print t() + "+ Connection from: "+ self.transport.getPeer().host                 

  def connectionLost(self, reason):                                                    

    self.sendMsg("- %s left." % self.name)                                           
    print t() + "- Connection lost: "+ self.name                                     
    self.factory.clients.remove(self) 
  def dataReceived(self, data):                                                        
        #print "data is ", data                                                      
            a = data.split(':')                                                      
            if len(a) > 1:                                                           
                    command = a[0]                                                   
                    content = a[1]                                                   


                    msg = ""                                                         
                    if command == "iam":                                             
                            self.name = content                                      
                            msg = self.name + " has joined"                          

                    elif command == "msg":                                           
                            msg = self.name + ": " + content                         
                    elif command  == "quit":                                         
                            self.transport.loseConnection()                          
                            return                                                   
                    elif command == "/ul":                                           
                            self.chatters()                                          
                            return()                                                 

                    print msg
                    self.sendMsg(msg)

  def username(self, line):                                                            

    for x in self.factory.clients:                                         
        if x.name == line:                                                 
            self.sendLine("This username is taken; please choose another")           
            return                                                                   

    self.name = line                                                                 
    self.chatters()                                                                  
    self.sendLine("You have been connected!")                                        
    self.sendLine("")                                                                
    self.count += 1                                                                  
    self.sendMsg("+ %s joined." % self.name)                                         
    print '%s~ %s connected as: %s' % (t(), self.transport.getPeer().host, self.name)

  def chatters(self):                                                                  
    x = len(self.factory.clients) - 1                                                
    s = 'is' if x == 1 else 'are'                                                    
    p = 'person' if x == 1 else 'people'                                             
    self.sendLine("There %s %i other %s connected:" % (s, x, p) )                    

    for client in self.factory.clients:                                              
        if client is not self:                                                       
            self.sendLine(client.name)                                               
    self.sendLine("")

  def sendMsg(self, message):                                                          

    for client in self.factory.clients:                                              
        client.transport.write( message + '\n')                                      



class EchoServerFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):                                         
protocol  = EchoProtocol                                                             
clients = []                                                                         

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                               
reactor.listenTCP(5001, EchoServerFactory())                                         
print "Chat Server Started"                                                          
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Several solution come to mind, you already have set of clients in `self.factory.clients`, you could use several different sets to group clients and then you can write messages only to that group, other more robust solutions could use some message broker such as RabbitMQ or very simple Redis PubSub.

Comment: ok trying for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code, I see you already created variable named group on your factory, so I guess you had similar idea, but try with dictionary instead of a list so you can name and access your groups more elegantly.

Of course this means that your `"msg"` command should have group specified so that you know to which group to send messages to.

```
class EchoServerFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):                                         
   protocol  = EchoProtocol                                                             
   clients = []
   groups = {}    

def dataReceived(self, data):                                                        
   # Split string ,error checking ...
   if command == "join":                                             
      self.factory.groups.get(content, []).append(self)  
   # handle other commands             

def sendMsg(self, message, group):                                                          
   for client in self.factory.groups[group]:                                              
      client.transport.write( message + '\n')
```

This is really trivial though, there is no scroll-back for example so new clients won't see chat history, message delivery is **not reliable** since you don't use any kind of acknowledgements to signal the server that the client has really received a message or that the server should resend the message to some clients.

Better, more robust solutions could perhaps include:

- Use [Twisted IRC server protocol](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRC.html)
- Use [TwistedWords](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords) instant messaging server/client (simple)
- [Redis PubSub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) to easily fanout a message from the single client to all other clients that subscribe on the same channel (unreliable, almost trivial to implement)
- Using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to route the messages to required clients or some other message broker (reliable, robust, much more setup then Redis or TwistedWords)

Here is a short explanation on what i mean with [reliable and unreliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_messaging).

> Reliable messaging is the concept of communicating messages across an
>   unreliable infrastructure whilst being able to make certain guarantees
>   about the successful transmission of the messages; for example, that
>   if the message is delivered, it is delivered at most once, or that all
>   messages successfully delivered arrive in a particular order.

Disclamer: I've only suggested the technologies and ideas that I have used in the past, there is probably hundreds of more ways to implement [simple,robust] group chat.

Comment: thanks a lot rebus for the help but still not able to run it completly ? stuck on how to pass group name through msg, any suggestions plz ?

Comment: Hi rebus can you elaborate more what should be the paramaters, I am stuck still not able to get desired output

Comment: You are already using `:` to separate the command name and the content as in `msg:hello`, one idea would be to maybe extend that to `msg:group:hello`. But all this is too broad for specific answer.